# Reasons for "DUPLICATE KEY" errors?

Tags: mysql

What are the reasons for "DUPLICATE KEY" errors in MySQL replication?

I am having master-master replication setup.  Assuming two masters, master1 and master2, data is inserted into master1 at all times.
The query I use is "INSERT INTO temp (temp_column2, temp_column3,...) VALUES ('XXX', 'YYY',...)" where temp_column1 is auto_increment column.
In my setup, two daemons insert data into master1 and it is creating a duplicate key error.

I can't figure out why it is happening.  Most of the time, when ever the issue occurs, the duplicate key error is a conflict between the row and its next row.

For example:

```
#### on master1 ####
       temp_column1, temp_column2, temp_column3, timestamp
Row1:         1      'XXX',        'YYY',         2011-12-28 12:00:00
Row2:         3      'AAA',        'BBB',         2011-12-28 12:00:00

#### on master2 (replication mysql instance) ####
       temp_column1, temp_column2, temp_column3, timestamp
Row1:         1      'AAA',        'BBB',         2011-12-28 12:00:00

Row2:    (Duplicate key error) when trying to insert row1 ('XXX', 'YYY')
```

So, I am updating Row2 id in master2 to fix replication.

Why are DUPLICATE KEY errors continuously occurring always?  Is there any solution to this?  Is it a mysql bug?

Comment: Is your AUTO_INCREMENT set up correctly for replication? … what are the CREATE TABLE commands for the table in question?

Answer (score 2):

The replication in mysql does not attempt to maintain a consistent state across all nodes in the database. There are clustering solutions which attempt to do this but generally (IME):

1. require huge amounts of synchronization data to be passed between nodes
2. are often much slower as a result
3. when they fail, they do so dramatically

Basically, you should always assume that there will be an unpredictable delay between DML operations on each node.

It looks like your problem has arisen because you are allowing inserts on more than one node and are using auto-increment fields without [setting the increment and offset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html) appropriately for the nodes.

Comment: No, I am always inserting rows only on one node at all times.  But, still I am facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error

If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: I don't think you addressed the actual problem at hand, instead knee-jerking into a very general description of what unique keys usually do.

Comment: Yes, I understand that an existing UNIQUE index value in the table causes a duplicate-key error.  I am interested in knowing why a UNIQUE key conflict arises in the first place.  In my example above, on master1 the order of insert is Row1 and Row2, but in my replication instance, the order of insert is Row2 followed by Row1.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of this bug:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61209

Check what values are for auto_increment_offset and innodb_autoinc_lock_mode on your servers and try to use the server with auto_increment_offset = 1.

There's my patch for this bug, but it's still waiting for any response from MySQL/Oracle.